# How to make a modal redirect to a url on react and bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I made a button and that button triggers a Modal on a React Component.

```
  //REACT COMPONENT
    
    import React from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    const BottomNavBar = ()=>{
    
    return (
            //NAVABAR
            <div style={{ marginTop: '100px' }}>
                {/* MODAL */}
                <div
                    className='modal fade'
                    id='exampleModalCenter'
                    tabindex='-1'
                    role='dialog'
                    aria-labelledby='exampleModalCenterTitle'
                    aria-hidden='true'
                >
                    <div
                        className='modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered'
                        role='document'
                    >
                        <div className='modal-content'>
                            <div className='modal-header'>
                                <h5
                                    className='modal-title'
                                    id='exampleModalLongTitle'
                                >
                                    CREAR
                                </h5>
                                <button
                                    type='button'
                                    className='close'
                                    data-dismiss='modal'
                                    aria-label='Close'
                                >
                                    <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div className='modal-body text-center'>
                                <Link
                                    to='/patient/create'
                                    className='btn btn-primary'
                                >
                                    CREAR USUARIO
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* MODAL */}
    
                <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-bottom bg-primary'>
                    <div className='container navbar-nav'>
                        {/* Right Icon Set */}
                        <div className='row  ml-auto mr-auto '>
                            <div className='nav-item col active'>
                                <Link
                                    className='nav-link'
                                    data-toggle='modal'
                                    data-target='#exampleModalCenter'
                                >
                                    <i className='far fa-plus-square fa-2x'></i>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        );
    
    }
    
    
    export default withRouter(BottomNavBar);
```

Everything works fine, the component when I click on the "LINK" it redirects to a page on my project.

BUT the modal remains active! in the other page.

I think is because I never "CALL" the "data-dismiss" property.

But how I can do it? I tried to put the property on the "LINK" but It doesnt work, It just close, but not redirect.

How I can perform that action... opens a modal and redirects to a page (And close that modal also).

Comment: You could attach an `onClick` handler to the `Link` to call the modal's onClose handler. If you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example we could better assist. From the included snippet it isn't visible at all how the modal is even being rendered.

Comment: Thanks! I just Edit the code of the component to give you more info.

Comment: So it seems the modal is *just part of* your navbar. Is there *any state* somewhere that controls when either the modal or navbar are visible and/or mounted? You've basically a component that takes no props and renders static JSX.

Comment: import React, { Fragment } from 'react';


import NavBar from './NavBar';
import BottomNavBar from './BottomNavBar';

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
 //Main Return
 return (
  <Fragment>
   <NavBar />
   <div className='container mt-3'>{children}</div>
    <BottomNavBar />
  </Fragment>
 );
};

export default Layout;

Comment: And the Layout is in the APP.js only this

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this but it should work for you:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const BottomNavBar = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => $("#exampleModalCenter").modal("hide");
  });
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
      {/* MODAL */}
      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="exampleModalCenter"
        tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
                CREAR
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body text-center">
              <Link to="/patient/create" className="btn btn-primary">
                CREAR USUARIO
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* MODAL */}

      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-bottom bg-primary">
        <div className="container navbar-nav">
          {/* Right Icon Set */}
          <div className="row  ml-auto mr-auto ">
            <div className="nav-item col active">
              <Link
                className="nav-link"
                data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
              >
                <i className="far fa-plus-square fa-2x"></i>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(BottomNavBar);
```

If you're using react you can try to use react-bootstrap.